# Are there any mistakes in the circuit which would cause overheating and damage to IR2110 driver IC?

Tags: pwm, inverter, mosfet-driver, igbt, sine

I’m designing a sine wave inverter. I bought 4  IR2110 ICs from local shop. All of them draws excess current and starts to overheat when I connect Vdd and Vss to 5v supply and Ground respectively. Voltage across Vdd and Vss drops to 3v as soon as I connect the supply. I also shorted Vss with COM. The circuit I used to test the IC is given below. Can anyone please confirm whether my circuit is wrong or the ICs are faulty.

[image]

Comment: Oh I think I see what you did for C3. You tied HIN to gnd. That's really misleading how it is drawn. In any case you need to wire everything up to test, not just the caps. Rotate the IC so it is easier to read the schematic because right now it is really difficult to read with orientation different and no pin names. Readability makes mistakes easier to find and more difficult to make. I'm spending all my time jumping between pinout tables, pinout diagrams and rotating it my head when reading the schematic.

Comment: I will update the schematic

Comment: You don't need to wire up bootstraps if not using the high side (I think) but your first diagram is not wired up enough so don't expect that one to work.

Comment: Oh I just saw another reason why it's so confusing. Your IC numbers don't run around the symbol the standard way. Either arrange it to be like the physical numbering, or rearrange them by function ignoring number order  so it makes a neat schematic. As is, your symbol is rotated to be confusing but inside that the order is flipped on one side to be even more confusing. That's why I kept tripping up over and over again reading things.

Comment: I've added pin names in the circuit. Hope that makes it more readable.

Comment: Thank you. Scanning it, I don't see anything immediately wrong. It should work if it really is as drawn. What voltage are you using for your LIN signal?

Comment: I tested with 5v and 3.3v. But I cannot even test this circuit, because the ic s taking too much current and overheating with time. So I disconnect the supply before completely burning the ic. Voltage across Vdd and Vss drops drastically.

Comment: Do you have any IC you have not put into a circuit? Measure the resistance between the power pins. It should not be low. Is your local shop reputable? Were they packaged properly?

Comment: Resistance b/w Vdd and Vss is several mega ohms.. my multimeter is showing OL

Comment: Check the resistance between every pin and every other pin. Is there any that reads unusually low?

Comment: I’ve 4 ics. 1 is showing 30 ohm b/w Vcc and com. I think it’s destroyed. Other two shows 110kohm across vcc and com. Last one shows OL(above 30mega ohm)

Comment: There are several mega ohms across all other pins

Comment: I agree the 30Ohm is dead. I think it's come to the point where you should show a photo of your circuit.

Comment: Give me some time..

Comment: I won't be able to check until tommorrow evening anyways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127332/discussion-between-vivek-vijayan-and-dknguyen).